# Can only access object properties with array syntax

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, object, collections

## Background

I have two methods that handle the import of an excel spread sheet, clean up fields (I.e. change "player_name" to "name"), filter out the invalid rows of data and the valid rows of data. If there is invalid data, it is returned to a Vue component, which gives the user the opportunity to correct the invalid data.

The initial submission is handled by `AdminImportPlayersController@store` and subsequent submissions (to fix invalid data) is handled by `AdminImportFixedPlayersController@store`.

Data is `collect`ed into a `Collection` upon post.

## Problem

With the initial submission, handled by `AdminImportPlayersController@store` (actually importing the excel file), I can access the data within the `Collection` with object syntax (i.e. `obj->prop`). However, using basically the same code in the `AdminImportFixedPlayersController@store` controller (still have to refactor, probably abstract body of functionality into a Facade.) is treating the 'object' as an `array`. Obviously it is actually an `array`, but I have not worked out why this is..

Controllers are posted below.

## Code

`AdminImportPlayersController@store`:

```
/**
 * Imports players from an excel spreadsheet.
 * Returns invalid players, if present.
 *
 * Teams are represented by their name in the submitted file.
 *
 * @param  App\HttpRequests\StoreImportPlayersFormRequest $request
 * @return Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(StoreImportPlayersFormRequest $request)
{
    $now = Carbon::now()->toW3cString();
    $fileName = 'players-import-' . $now . '.xls';

    // moving imported file to local storage
    $request->file('players')->move(storage_path('/import/excel/'), $fileName);

    // creating a Collection from the results returned from file
    $player_data = collect(Excel::load(storage_path('import/excel/') . $fileName)->get());

    // clean up data structure
    $player_data = $player_data->map(function ($player) {
        $player['name'] = $player->player_name;
        unset($player['player_name']);
        return $player;
    });

    // get all invalid entries
    $invalid_player_data = $player_data->filter(function ($player) {
        \Log::info($player);
        return ! Team::where('name', $player->team)->first() || $player->name == null;
    })->values();


    // get all valid entries
    $valid_player_data = $player_data->filter(function ($player) {
        return Team::where('name', $player->team)->first() && $player->name !== null;
    })->values();

    // save players
    $valid_player_data->each(function ($player) {
        $team = Team::where('name', $player->team)->first();
        $team->players()->attach(
            Player::create([
                'name' => $player->name,
                'temp' => 0,
            ])
        );
    });

    return response()->json(['invalid_player_data' => $invalid_player_data->all()], 200);
}
```

`AdminImportFixedPlayersController@store`:

```
/**
 * Stores fixed player data, after re-submission due to invalid data.
 * Returns invalid players, if still present.
 * Teams are represented by their id.
 *
 * @param  App\Http\Requests\StoreImportFixedPlayersFormRequest $request
 * @return Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(StoreImportFixedPlayersFormRequest $request)
{
    $player_data = collect($request->players);

    // get all invalid entries
    $invalid_player_data = $player_data->filter(function ($player) {
        return ! Team::where('id', $player['team'])->first() || $player['name'] == null;
    })->values();

    // get all valid entries
    $valid_player_data = $player_data->filter(function ($player) {
        return Team::where('id', $player['team'])->first() && $player['name'] !== null;
    })->values();

    // save players
    $valid_player_data->each(function ($player) {
        $team = Team::where('id', $player['team'])->first();
        $team->players()->attach(
            Player::create([
                'name' => $player['name'],
                'temp' => 0,
            ])
        );
    });

    return response()->json(['invalid_player_data' => $invalid_player_data->all()], 200);
}
```

Note that when saying something like

```
return ! Team::where('id', $player->team)->first() || $player->name == null;
```

in `AdminImportPlayersController` (the controller that handles the initial importation), it is legal and no exceptions are thrown.

However, the same code, when used in `AdminImportFixedPlayersController`, throws an exception and I can only legally use the following syntax:

```
return ! Team::where('id', $player['team'])->first() || $player['name'] == null;
```

Sorry for the lengthy question, just like to be thorough!

Please ask for more information if needed.

I have logged out the values for the `$player_data` in both methods at various locations. The value of `$player_data`, in `AdminImportFixedPlayersController`, after being collected from the request is equal to something like:

```
[{"name": "ashley", "team" : 1}, ..., ...].
```

Why can't I access the properties of these objects, without using array-like syntax?

Comment: So `$player_data` in the 'AdminImportFixedPlayersController' controller is a Array and not a collection object?

Comment: That makes sense. However, I assumed that putting ```$request->players``` into a ```Collection``` would mean that I would be dealing with a ```Collection```. Perhaps the data is contained in a ```Collection```, but not each set of values is a ```Collection```?

Comment: Also, even if the data in an ```array```, I should, when iterating over it, be able to access the objects as objects, not an array. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

## Current Solution

After creating a collection from `$request->players`

```
$player_data = collect($request->players);
```

I am mapping each `Player` to its own `Collection` and for each `Player` in $player_data, setting properties on each `Player` to equal the value of related data, accessed as a normal array: `$player->name = $player['name'];`.

Solution:

```
   $player_data = collect($request->players);

    // turn each 'player' into a collection and create properties that are accessible via object->method notation
   $player_data = $player_data->map(function ($player) {
        $player = collect($player);
        $player->name = $player['name'];
        $player->team = $player['team'];
        return $player;
    });
```